# How to fetch field Names inside an Array of Collection in mongoDB?

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql, aggregation-framework

I am trying to fetch the field Names present in the mongo DB collection, so far I have built till here :

```
db.getCollection('appd_application_master').aggregate([
{"$project":{"arrayofkeyvalue":{"$objectToArray":"$$ROOT"}}},
  {"$unwind":"$arrayofkeyvalue"},
  {"$group":{"_id":null,"allkeys":{"$addToSet":"$arrayofkeyvalue.k"}}},
  {"$unwind":"$allkeys"}
])
```

But the problem is if the collection holds any array then the fields inside it I'm unable to access, can some please help or guide in the right direction?TIA

Here is a sample record of the collection

```js
{
  "_class": "com.json.SvnCommitMst",
  "_id": "38735",
  "author": "10662365",
  "commitDate": ISODate( "2021-09-30T08:28:01.159Z"),
  "isLatest": false,
  "mapSvnFilesMst": [
    {
      "_id": ObjectId( "618df1b32109446cb6ef58d6"),
      "commitAction": "MODIFY"
    }
  ],
  "message": "Rohit:\n\nUser Repo tool validation changes",
  "projectToolId": 92
}
```

The response I'm getting with the current query:

```
{
    "_id" : null,
    "allkeys" : [ 
        "isLatest", 
        "author", 
        "_id", 
        "message", 
        "projectToolId", 
        "_class", 
        "mapSvnFilesMst", 
        "commitDate"
    ]
}
```

Comment: can you post the output you want to get also?

Comment: maybe [this?](https://mongoplayground.net/p/W0TnHchV4Dl)

Comment: @Takis_ I want the array details which are present inside the field mapSvnFilesMst

Answer (score 2):

Based on the assumption that you know the names of your array(s) you can use two `$project` stages to get all keys combined. In both of them you can refer to more than one variable.

The [$let](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/) operator becomes handy to get rid of additional stages:

```
{
    $addFields: {
        mapSvnFilesMst: {
            $reduce: {
                input: "$mapSvnFilesMst",
                initialValue: [],
                in: {
                    $setUnion: [
                        "$$value",
                        {
                            $let: {
                                vars: {
                                    kv: { $objectToArray: "$$this" }
                                },
                                in: "$$kv.k"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
{
    $project: {
        allKeys: {
            $setUnion: [
                "$mapSvnFilesMst",
                {
                    $let: {
                        vars: { kv: { $objectToArray: "$$ROOT" } },
                        in: "$$kv.k"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/n6wVD3vF1SZ)

You can also try below query to scan your documents without specifying the name of any array - works only for one level of arrays (without recursion):

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    $project: {
        allKeys: {
            $reduce: {
                input: { $objectToArray: "$$ROOT" },
                initialValue: [],
                in: {
                    $setUnion: [
                        "$$value",
                        {
                            $cond: {
                                if: { $eq: [ { $type: "$$this.v" }, "array" ] },
                                then: {
                                    $setUnion: [
                                        ["$$this.k"],
                                        {
                                            $reduce: {
                                                input: "$$this.v",
                                                initialValue: [],
                                                in: {
                                                    $setUnion: [
                                                        "$$value",
                                                        {
                                                            $let: {
                                                                vars: { kv: { $objectToArray: "$$this" } },
                                                                in: "$$kv.k"
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    ]
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                else: [ "$$this.k" ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}])
```

[Mongo Playground (2)](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vcd2CryUSL-)

Comment: Could be some way of doing this without knowing wich field is the array?

Comment: @RubénVega modified my answer